# Need an Explanation About this little python code of list having other default functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

I am new to programming and while learning I came across this code to find the second-highest number in the list, A few things I don't understand in this code are: How map() & set() functions are used and what is the purpose of sys.stdin.readline() rather we can use input() ?
And I don't understand the purpose of "`_`" in `_ = sys.stdin.readline()` line.
Please help.

```
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    _ = sys.stdin.readline()
    a = set(map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split()))

    print (sorted(a)[-2])
```

Comment: I think it is redundant. You don't need first line after main

Comment: Well, it *reads a line*. And then does nothing with it. Hence, discarding the first input line.

Comment: You need some tutorials. Read the documentation for map, set etc. experiment with them. Asking such basic things to be explaind to you is not target for this platform - it is what is best conveyed in 1 on 1 tutoring or turorials. Beside that you got 3-4 questions and we aim for 1 question per post - see [ask]

Comment: Where did you find that code? I wouldn't use it as an example.

Answer (score 1):

- there is no difference of using `sys.stdin.readline()` instead of `input()` consider it's the same, let's say you read `1 5 98 5`
- as it uses `split()` you have a list of string, like `["1", "5", "98", "5"]`
- the `map` operation applies conversion to `int` to each, to get `[1, 5, 98, 5]`
- then give it to `set` to get unique elements `[1, 5, 98]`

In fact this program read values from the user, and return the second bigger value

Answer (score 0):

**

### Sys.stdin.readline()

**
Stdin stands for standard input which is a stream from which the program read its input data. This method is slightly different from the input() method as it also reads the escape character entered by the user. More this method also provides the parameter for the size i.e. how many characters it can read at a time.

**

### Input()

**
This function first takes the input from the user and then evaluates the expression, which means Python automatically identifies whether the user entered a string or a number or list. If the input provided is not correct then either syntax error or exception is raised by Python.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-input-and-sys-stdin-readline/